# How to calculate moving average DAYS of a date column

Tags: mysql

I have these columns and data
Sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE Orders(customerid int, orderdate datetime, orderqty int);
INSERT into Orders(customerid, orderdate, orderqty) VALUES
    (1,'2020-11-25',100),(1,'2020-11-27',160),(2,'2020-12-05',3490),
    (1,'2020-11-29',293),(2,'2020-12-07',293),(1,'2020-12-01',382);
```

sqlfiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d90aaf/1/0

From this data, I want to find out the date difference in last 3 rows by each customer.
an example output would be:

```
customerid, last 3 orders average days between orders,sum of orderqty for last 3 order
1, 2,835
2, 2,3783
```

I have tried datediff() but I can't achieve this result by that function.

Comment: I don't think the result example matches the data you have presented? Or does it? And should we keep the order of the data as you present it, or do the more sensible thing and order them by date?

Comment: ordering them doesn't matter really as  the group by will be customer. But if the latest ordering customers can be listed in ascending order that's a plus

Comment: the example matches the data

Comment: What does "orders average days" mean???

Comment: @Strawberry I added sqlfiddle. hopefully it helps

Comment: @YunfeiChen not sure how to put it. I want to take last 3 orders by a customer, and then find out the average days difference between these 3 orders. if an order was repeated on consecutive days. Then the average would be 1day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't figure out better trick for latest 3 orders. This works, but probably with not good performance with large tables:

```
SELECT o3.customerid,DATEDIFF(Latest1,IFNULL(Latest3,Latest2))/IF(Latest3 IS NULL,1,2) AS avgDiff,SUM(oQ.orderqty) AS qty3orders FROM
(SELECT o2.*,MAX(ooo.orderdate) AS Latest3 FROM 
(SELECT o1.*,MAX(oo.orderdate) AS Latest2 FROM 
(SELECT customerid,MAX(orderdate) AS Latest1 FROM Orders GROUP BY customerid) o1 
JOIN Orders oo ON o1.customerid=oo.customerid AND oo.orderdate<o1.Latest1 GROUP BY o1.customerid) o2
LEFT JOIN Orders ooo ON o2.customerid=ooo.customerid AND ooo.orderdate<o2.Latest2 GROUP BY o2.customerid) o3
JOIN orders oQ ON o3.customerid=oQ.customerid AND oQ.orderdate>=COALESCE(o3.Latest3,o3.Latest2,o3.Latest1) GROUP BY o3.customerid
```

Comment: how large does the table has to be before this is slowed down significantly?

Comment: I tried it on my real table with over 100 000 rows and works fine, so it's not dramatical. Of course there must be an index on customerid.

Comment: is the index created automatically because customerid is a foreign key column?

Comment: I'm not sure about that, but you can try it.

Comment: How large is (or is expected to be) your table?

Comment: should be well under 100k I hope so. I don't have real data for it yet.

Comment: So it's OK. And yes mysql creates indexes on columns with foreign key automatically - see more on [https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html). So I think you're fine with this solution until million of records :-)